# FlatList not updating after CRUD in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, flatlist

What I'm trying to do is to pass new data to a API and display it in a FlatList. All my CRUD-methods are passing, but my FlatList wont display the changes until I refresh my "App.js". The code in my "App.js" (as shown below) contains the "delete" method, which is working and my FlatList updates it right away, I guess it is since the state is local and the FlatList can find it. But when I use "PUT" and "POST" methods, that is declared in other components it doesn't react to it.

I'm a complete noob in react-native and when it comes to navigation within it. Any tips on how to solve this puzzle?

```
class Fetch extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        
        title: 'Blomster Boden',
    };
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isLoading: true }
     
        this.forceUpdate();

        
      
    }
    actionOnRow(item) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { item });
        this.state
    }
    editOnRow(item) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit', { item });
    this.state
    }
    suckulenter(item) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Info', { item });
        this.state
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData()
    }
    
    getData = () => {
         fetch('http://192.168.10.135:3000/blommor/')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson
                },
                );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
    

    delete(_id) {
        fetch('http://192.168.10.135:3000/blommor/' + _id,
            {
                method: "DELETE",
 
            }).then((result) => {
                result.json().then(() => {
                    alert("Blomman har tagits bort!")
                    this.getData()
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.ActivityIndicator}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
            
        }
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container } >   
                <View style={styles.body}>
                    <Text h1 style={styles.h1}>Välkommen till blomsterboden</Text>
                   

                    <Card style={styles.card}>
                     
                        <Title style={styles.cardTitle}>Lista av våra blommor</Title>

         
                            


                         <FlatList  data={this.state.dataSource}

                        extraData={this.state}

                        renderItem={({ item }) =>

                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>       
                                this.actionOnRow(item)}>
                                <Text style={styles.listTextStyle} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='middle'>
                                    <Text style={styles.Namn} >  {item.Namn}  </Text> 
                                    <IconButton
                                        icon="arrow-right"
                                        size={15}
                                    />

                                    <IconButton 
                                        icon="pencil"
                                        color={Colors.green400}
                                        size={20}
                                        title="Edit"
                                        onPress={() => this.editOnRow(item)}
                                    />

                                    <IconButton
                                        icon="delete"
                                        size={20}
                                        title="Ta bort"
                                        onPress={() => this.delete(item._id)}
                                    />

                                </Text>
                                
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>                         

                        }

                        keyExtractor={item => item._id.toString()}
                            /> 

                    </Card>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to know, _where_ and _how_ the "PUT" and "POST" methods are implemented and if the state is modified in any way from outside.

Comment: So, the "POST" and "PUT" method is in two seperated .js-files within a "components"-map. The "POST".js however is a modal that i call for onPress on my App.js, where i type in values and submits into my API - but its not updating as said before. the "PUT" is made on another screen that i get to by clicking the "this.editOnRow" in my "App.js". And i guess the problem is that my "extraData={this.state}" that is supposed to update the list on change, doesnt recognize the state from the other components. But its too late for me now to change to redux, and there should be another way.

Comment: Instead of passing a state, you might passa callback function which handles the state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66803297/7451109

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will try that out.. I wish i knew how to do it, but i actually have no idea, and while googling i find nothing that suits my problem. Im still a complete beginner to these kinds of stuff, and to have like an overall explanation in a video doesnt give me much. But imma keep fighting! :D Once again, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll write you a short code snippet in my answer in a bit!

Comment: Wow, thanks!  really helpful. So, the first bit of code, the one in the parent component (wich in my case is App.js) can be written anywhere? i mean the onStateChange(newState) can be written over my fetch for example. And the other one just below it (without it affecting the result). And the one in the child component (EditForm.js in my case) can also be written anywhere? and what should key:value be changed to? My API strings? Once again, thank you, youre a legend!

Comment: App.js would handle **global** state. That means, everything has to be passed all the way down to the great-grandchild component. My idea was to put it in the Fetch component. But if EditForm.js is not a child component of App js that'd be the way to go. In that case, the onStateChange() in App.js has to trigger a method in Fetch after being triggered itself. Key:value would probably be dataSource and responseJSON or whatever you need to change the state.

Comment: Alright. I just gotta admit im not good enough even to understand what u just said. Im really sorry. Im gonna ask too much from you now and add a link to my code, only the components and the homepage "App.js" . If you want to please take a look and see for yourself if its solveable. Otherwise im glad for all your help this far. Here's the code -> https://easyupload.io/gthx3s

Comment: No problem. Without asking, you couldn't get answers to grow with as a programmer. Sorry for my late reply. I'm currently looking at your code and I noticed, you have two `render()` methods in your App.js: On in line 83 and one in line 87. As far as I am concerned, that cannot work.

Comment: But besides that, the code looks more or less the way I described the changes. Just one thing, I noticed: The key in the object you pass to the callback is `key` but your state doesn't have a key called `key`. So you'd have to pass the actual key you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Well that happen because your database is not realtime database ! so when you navigate between screens you will want to use an event listener to refresh your list, every time you go and add post and get back to list the navigation listener will be triggered and will refresh your list, so here is your code updated:

```
    class Fetch extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            
            title: 'Blomster Boden',
        };
      
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { isLoading: true }
         
            this.forceUpdate();
    
            
          
        }
        actionOnRow(item) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { item });
            this.state
        }
        editOnRow(item) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit', { item });
        this.state
        }
        suckulenter(item) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Info', { item });
            this.state
        }


  //An event listener that will trigger when screen is focused
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      this.getData()
    });
  }

  //Clean up the event listener
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

        getData = () => {
             fetch('http://192.168.10.135:3000/blommor/')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        dataSource: responseJson
                    },
                    );
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
        
    
        delete(_id) {
            fetch('http://192.168.10.135:3000/blommor/' + _id,
                {
                    method: "DELETE",
     
                }).then((result) => {
                    result.json().then(() => {
                        alert("Blomman har tagits bort!")
                        this.getData()
                    })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    
    
        render() {
            if (this.state.isLoading) {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.ActivityIndicator}>
                        <ActivityIndicator />
                    </View>
                )
                
            }
            
            return (
                <View style={styles.container } >   
                    <View style={styles.body}>
                        <Text h1 style={styles.h1}>Välkommen till blomsterboden</Text>
                       
    
                        <Card style={styles.card}>
                         
                            <Title style={styles.cardTitle}>Lista av våra blommor</Title>
    
             
                                
    
    
                             <FlatList  data={this.state.dataSource}
    
                            extraData={this.state}
    
                            renderItem={({ item }) =>
    
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>       
                                    this.actionOnRow(item)}>
                                    <Text style={styles.listTextStyle} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='middle'>
                                        <Text style={styles.Namn} >  {item.Namn}  </Text> 
                                        <IconButton
                                            icon="arrow-right"
                                            size={15}
                                        />
    
                                        <IconButton 
                                            icon="pencil"
                                            color={Colors.green400}
                                            size={20}
                                            title="Edit"
                                            onPress={() => this.editOnRow(item)}
                                        />
    
                                        <IconButton
                                            icon="delete"
                                            size={20}
                                            title="Ta bort"
                                            onPress={() => this.delete(item._id)}
                                        />
    
                                    </Text>
                                    
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>                         
    
                            }
    
                            keyExtractor={item => item._id.toString()}
                                /> 
    
                        </Card>
```

Comment: Hi! Wow, real greatful for your comment - thanks! I tried your example out, but now im getting  "Can't find variable: navigation" at the componentDidMount section.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this.props.navigation , updated my answer

Comment: Yea, it actually made difference, and i might be close. However, now im stuck on loadingscreen when i open App.js. I can see the navigation-title, so the app is running. But a loadingwheel is the only thing i see i the "contentscreen". No errormessage, nothing  - just that it doesnt stop loading.

Comment: I changed "focus" to "willFocus" and it worked!. My FlatList still seems to be a mess though. After i edit a post the FlatList starts glitching and text flying around all over the place. Same goes for when i add a post in my API through a modal on the App.js, it doesnt show right away.. So im still far away from done it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to listen to changes. You either pass a function from your component to the other components if they are in the same tree. This function can then be called as a callback function after their respective "PUT" or "POST" action is complete. The function itself will then set the state the same way as in your "DELETE" method.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...
    onStateChange(newState) {
        this.setState(newState);
    }

    render() {
        return <ChildComponent onParentStateChange={this.onStateChange} />
    }
    // ...
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...
    onStateChange() {
        this.props.onParentStateChange({
            key: value
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

If they are not in the same tree or you don't like passing callbacks around, you may opt for a more global solution by using [reducers](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-reducer).